# Pandas：Aggregate by numerical column name and give error when substitution

Tags: python, pandas

In order to eliminate variations at the time of measurement, I want to compile in a specific range.

For example, I want to sum the column name in the range of ± 0.1 of the integer and assign it to an integer column. However, I can not substitute because of a shape error.

I think that it is caused by converting the type of the column, but what should I do about it?

Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import  numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.arange(0,10000,1).reshape(100,100))
df.columns = np.arange(0,10,0.1)

print(df.head())
df.columns = df.columns.astype(float)
temp = df.columns.values

for n in np.arange(1, 9, 1):
 l = n - 0.1
 m = n + 0.1
 calc_n = temp[np.where((temp >= l) & (temp <= m))]
 calc = np.sum(df[df.columns.intersection(calc_n)], axis=1)
 n_position = temp[np.where(temp == n)]
 df[n_position] = calc.values
```

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (100,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ValueError is because `n_position` is an array. So `df[n_position]` gives you a dataframe instead of a column.

It is usually not a good idea to use floats as indexes. And you should be careful when comparing floats. This line `calc_n = temp[np.where((temp >= l) & (temp <= m))]` won't always give accurate results.

For starter, try:

```
for n in np.arange(1, 9, 1):
    margin = 0.101     # set your own margin
    calc_n = np.where(np.abs(temp-n) < margin)
    df[n] = df.iloc[:,calc_n[0]].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: df.iloc [:, calc - n [0]]. sum  It is a good solution.


  I will not use flot next time.

  Thank you very much.